# How to make the background darker in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, popup

How can I make the background darker with bootstrap? I have found this code but have no idea where I can adjust the background or what kind of css code I must add to my style.

Found the code here:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS that is controlling the backdrop color is within the file modals.less and is controlled by the code below

```
.modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1040;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

To make the background darker just overwrite the class `.modal-backdrop` within your own stylesheet and add a different background color.

Within the same less file there is a class called `.modal-backdrop .in` This class is controlling the opacity of the background.

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}
```

You can overwrite this if the opacity is not what you're after too.

Comment: Thanks, I really never found this solution

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the my answer as the right answer if this has worked for you.